# Process and delete lines from file, stop if CancellationToken is send

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream, cancellation-token, binaryreader

I have to process the lines of a file that contain path and status information and start an upload operation for the line/path. In some cases the upload might fail, so that I have to keep the line, in other cases the line can be deleted when the upload was successful. The main problem is, that everything is running in the background and that the user can close the software whenever he wants. In that case I set a Cancellation-token and the file operation finishes.
Until now the file was always very small. So I copied all the lines that were still needed into a new file and replaced the old one.
Simplified code:

```
bool valid=false;
bool cancelled=false;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename_tmp, false))
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename)) //alternative:
            // foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            // process each line of file
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                rowCnt++;
                //separate line into content:
                string[] content = line.Split(delimiter);
                if (canceltoken.IsCancellationRequested && (rowCnt > 3))
                {
                    cancelled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    data_path = content[0];
                    //start upload:
                    valid = UploadData(data_path);
                }
                if( cancelled || valid==false)
                {
                     sw.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", data_path, uploadCnt,
                         DateTime.Now.ToString(), errorMsg);
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
File.Replace(filename_tmp, filename, filename_backup);
```

Now we have a situation where the file can get very big and I'm afraid, that copying everything into a new file will take too long. The user currently gets a message, that there are still processes running and that the software will close afterwards. After 1-5 sec the software was closed so far. Now it will take longer and I don't want the user to use task manager to kill the process.
What is the best way to process lines and delete it afterwards? I have full control over the file, because I write it. So I can define the format and writer myself (e.g. `StreamWriter` vs. `BinaryWriter`).

I thought of 2 possible options:

1. Process the whole file. Set a status flag for every row (like 1=remove me, 2=has to be processed/kept). After the file was processed iterate again over the lines and copy the needed ones. In case of an cancellation, keep the old file.

I would love to do something like:

```
var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => l.Contains("remove me") ==false);
File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);
```

But that would require that I write to the same line to change the status. I'm not sure if thats working. I could use a BinaryWriter to overwrite the "flag", but then I couldn't use the above line and would need to iterate over every line again.

2. Process file from the end using seek. If I would use a `BinaryWriter` I would exactly know the length of the lines, so that would not be a problem. Write lines with error that need to be processed again in an extra file. "Cut" the original file at the last processed line with `FileStream.SetLength`. This would result in 2 files (original one with non processed lines, second file with lines which need to be processed again). But I don't know yet, how to handle the extra file. I could process this one first next time I start, but then I could get more and more files which seems wrong.

I'm somehow stuck here and I have no idea how to further proceed. Any hints would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Rather than recording each line that wasn't uploaded yet, why not only record the last line that was successfully uploaded? Then if the program is restarted, continue from that line.

Comment: problem is, that I would loose lines in between. It might be that I upload 4 lines with success, then have a problem in the next two lines, but afterwards upload 100 lines with success. How to keep track of the 2 lines with an error?

Comment: The lines with errors would still be logged into a different file.

Comment: After all lines in the main file are processed, then lines in the error file would be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing (or marking) all unprocessed lines after cancellation I would invert the problem: Define all jobs (one per line), write it in a "queue" and delete it after the upload finishes.

To persist your queue, you can use [LiteDb](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB). It's a small and handy NoSQL file database, so you don't have the overhead of an OR Mapper.

The logic may look like this:

1. Define an UploadJob class with your content and some additional properties (URL, ...)
2. Write the list of jobs into a LiteDB collection.
3. Iterate over each job.
4. After a job has been successfully completed delete this item in LiteDB.

Comment: in this case I could work directly in the local database and wouldn't need any file operations. Is that right? Do I even need the queue? I'm always afraid that a database might crash and needs a repair. But it is way I totally forgot to think about ;-).

Comment: The queue is in fact your database collection (it works like a queue). You could delete an item with one statement (`coll.Delete(id)`). If you open the database in shared mode (see https://www.litedb.org/docs/connection-string/) the engine closes the database file after each operation. I use this database in production in an Azure app service, it is not the fastest, but very robust.